# performBatchUpdates doesn't animate cell subviews

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` for animating collection cells using a `UIGestureRecognizer` attached to my `UICollectionView`.

That's what I'm doing in the `UIGestureRecognizer` callback :

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGPoint t = [sender translationInView:self.myCollection];
    if( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
    {
    ...
    }
    else if( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged )
    {
        // update cells size & position at each iteration
        [self.myCollectionLayout updateWithOffset:offset];
    }
    else if( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
    {
        [_collection performBatchUpdates:^{

            // animate cells to final size & position
            [self.myCollectionLayout gestureFinalize];
        }];
    }
}
```

Everything goes well when the user is interacting, but when he stop, `performBatchUpdates` is called to animate cells to a final frame, cells are well animated but the views contained under cells are jumping from the current frame to the final frame without animation.
That's the same thing with supplementary views.

Is there a way to have a fluid transitions for subviews too ?